# Form Validation - Compare Column Data

Tags: column, form, validation

I'm needing some assistance with Form Validation.

I have a column inside my sharepoint listed called "**Payroll Close Day**". This column allows the end user to select from a choice of values being **"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday".**

I have added another column called "**Period End Processing Day**", set up the exact settings.

I need some advice to understandable if it is possible to:

1. Stop the user selecting the same day in the "**Period End Processing
   Day**" as what is selected in the "**Payroll Close Day**".
2. When the user selects the "**Period End Processing Day**", ensure the
   day selected is the "**Payroll Close Day**" + 1. So if they select
   **Tuesday** in the **"Payroll Close Day**", the "**Period End Processing Day**"
   must be **Wednesday**.

Thanks in advance and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to list Settings - > Validation Settings

Add following formula there inside text area :

```
    =EXACT(TEXT(WEEKDAY(Date1)+1,"ddd"),TEXT(WEEKDAY(Date2),"ddd"))
```

Replace Date1 and Date2 with your field names.

And in User Message input area add suitable validation message.This message will be displayed in the form when your condition does not satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

If the Period End Processing Day is always the next working day, perhaps best to avoid the user having to complete it. Instead, run some workflow to look at the Payroll Close Day and populate the PEPD accordingly.

Comment: Never thought of this idea. Easy enough to do. :)